# Mootools hide/show div on scroll

Tags: scroll, mootools

I am trying to add a position fixed to a div after 100px are scrolled down from the top of the page, and position relative if less than 100px have been scrolled.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('scroll',function(e) {
  if ($(this).scroll > 100) {
      $$('.my_element').setStyles({
          position: "fixed"
      });
  } else {
      $$('.my_element').setStyles({
          position: "relative"
      });
  }
});
</script>
```

I can use only Mootools or pure JS, no jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can, of course, use David Walsh's ScrollSpy - http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

else, use `window.getScroll().y` to get the current scrollTop etc.

Comment: Thanks, window.getScroll().y is exactly what I was looking for.